# annotation dependency from module not working

Tags: android, gradle, module, dependencies, cannot-find-symbol

build.gradle

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy {
    force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
}}
```

Async Task

`import android.annotation.MainThread;
import android.annotation.Nullable;
import android.annotation.WorkerThread;`

Any idea why  the above imports cannot be resolved?

Comment: Forgot to define dependency?

Comment: @thokuest Where and How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I know nothing about Android development.

In Gradle, dependencies are defined in the `dependencies` configuration block like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
}
```

Read mir about this in the [dependencies userguide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html).

`resolutionStrategy` in contrast, is used to control which version of a particular dependency to use in case a version conflict occurs (transitive dependencies) beside other [use cases](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html).